# Text inside TR is displayed outside the table

Tags: html

The following code used to work nicely for me in the past but now its no longer working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>when
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>when
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>when
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The text "when" used to displayed correctly in the same row. But now getting that text outside the table. ie., the text is displayed thrice and then below that the table is displayed.

Is there anything wrong? I tried on Mac -Chrome/FF/Safari.

Comment: You cannot put a text directly inside tr, you need to put it inside td, what your are doing is an invalid markup

Comment: Yea am changing it now as per the standards!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `<tr>` is not meant to contain actual text, only `<td>`s.  If you want to display text in the roll.. you have to use a td to do so.

As noted by the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html).

Comment: Thanks! for super quick response! Yes I realized that i need to add <td>. But am curious why it used to worked in the past but not now?

Comment: @Srikanth I would guess because of a bug in the implementation by the browser, or perhaps a programmer left something out.  Also, if this answer solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the outlined checkmark, when it lets you.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for the note, fixed.  I was likely thinking of css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You must put them in other TD.

like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

     <table border="1">
       <tr>
    <th></th>
      <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>when</td>
    <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>when</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put td in a table cell, like this

```
 <td>when</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look in [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp)

Correct is:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```